# Inferring generics of an Optional in Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to implement a method which returns an Optional of either classes: A,B,C extends Mother.

I have no idea where to start. I tried something like this

```
    private Optional<U> get(String query,U u){
    }

A = c.get("Looking for an A",A.class)
B = c.get("Looking for an B",B.class)
C = c.get("Looking for an C",C.class)
C = c.get("Looking for an k",k.class) // Exception, K doesn't extend `Mother`
```

Comment: It’s not really clear. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost there, here's a better version.

```
private <U extends Mother> Optional<U> get(String query, Class<U> clazz) {
    ...
}
```

The bounded type parameter makes sure can only pass a subclass of `Mother` (or `Mother.class` itself).

Comment: Ohhh!! can you give some reference for this? I would like to read more

Comment: Uh, err... well https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html that should give you a full walkthrough. Unless you have a specific question about the code?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html, more specifically.